# Looking for elements with specific depth in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function in pure JavaScript witn no framework to get all specific tags, but only from first level under parent.

For example: I need to call some function on first `<ul>` and get all `<li>` from first level of it (`<li>` with text 1.2 and `<li>` with text 2.1)

```
<div id="sideNavigation">
    <ul>
       <li class=" act open  "> 
          1.2
          <ul>
             <li class="  ">
                1.2
                <ul>
                   <li class="  ">
                      1.3
                      <ul>
                         <li class="  ">1.4</li>
                      </ul>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="  ">
          2.1
          <ul>
             <li class="  ">2.2.1</li>
             <li class="  ">2.2.2</li>
             <li class="  ">2.2.3</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've been trying to do it like this:

```
var allLi = document.getElementById("sideNavigation").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

but it returns all `<li>` in this div not only first level `<li>`. Do you have any quick method to solve my problem or do I have to implement a new function to detect depth of nodes

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes

Comment: Yeah, it may be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#sideNavigation > ul > li');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute .children to get those "li"

```
var firstDepthLi = document.getElementById("sideNavigation").children[0].children;
```

If you want a generic function you can create something like:

```
var getElementsByDepth = function(el, tagname, depth) {
       var children = el.children;
       var res = new Array();
       for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
          if (children[i].tagName == tagname) {
             res.push(children[i]);
             if (depth > 0)
                 res.concat(getElementsByDepth(children[i], tagname, depth-1));
          }
       }
       return res;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off using `.childNodes` rather than `.children` as the former has better browser support. You can just do a simple replacement without having to change any of your code.

Comment: Should also make a note of the fact that the tagname argument would have to be all upper case as `.tagName` always returns in uppercase for HTML. (or could use a `.toUpperCase()` in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var allLi = document.getElementById("sideNavigation").getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
```

That should return the first `li` element out of all `li`'s on the page. Change the zero at the end to a different number to get a different element. You could even set a variable for the value:

```
var liNum = 0;
var allLi = document.getElementById("sideNavigation").getElementsByTagName("li")[liNum];
```

And in a function:

```js
function getLi(depth) {
    var specificLi = document.getElementById("sideNavigation").getElementsByTagName("li")[depth];
    return specificLi;
}
    
var firstLi = getLi(0);
console.log(firstLi);
```

```html
<div id="sideNavigation">
    <ul>
        <li>First list tag</li>
        <li>Second list tag</li>
        <li>Third list tag</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And to make the function even shorter, you could just do:

```
function getLi(depth) {
    return document.getElementById("sideNavigation").getElementsByTagName("li")[depth];
}
```

That should work. :)